# How to tell Gradle where to search for Android's support libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, command-line, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to catch up on an Android project built with Gradle, and having trouble just with Android's support libraries:

```
$ ./gradlew
[ ... succeeding part ... ]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myproject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myproject:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         android_core: myproject:unspecified
```

The `appcompat` libraries are available in my SDK extra folder, and my environment is well set (`ANDROID_HOME` and the sometimes redundant `ANDROID_SKD` too). I am still using Ant on other projects, and all build well.

I have added `mavenCentral()` to the `build.gradle` configuration file, reluctantly to both the top project and sub-project.

Now I guess I need to tell Gradle to search my local installs, but I did not find how to do it. I am also surprised that I would need to change anything to the build configuration. It works well for others, although all others use Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to the problem.

Although I have the Android Support Library working well with Ant-based projects, it turns out that Gradle (seems to) expect another flavour of the libraries. After installing the *Android Support Repository*, everything started to work fine.

If you are facing the same problem, you may check the SDK install for the repository.

[image: Android SDK Manager on Extras]

On the CLI:

```
$ android list sdk -a | grep "Android Support"
 146- Android Support Repository, revision 25
 147- Android Support Library, revision 23.1.1
```

I should thank my offline colleague Kuwata-san for leading to this solution!

Answer (score -1):

You should add jcenter() in your root build.gradle file,like this

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```